# Submissions of different webforms in one page without extra access

Tags: views, webforms

I searched a lot and did not find any good advice, so I ask support form community. please help !
.
Suppose this scenario and suggest me what should I do ?!
.
I have three webform > Webform A, Webform B, Webform C .
and have three Content type which referenced to those webforms :
Content type P ( Webform A )
Content type Q ( Webform B )
Content type T ( Webform C )
and also have three Roles : Role 1(Admin), Role 2(Content Creator), Role 3 (Submitter)
.
.
Users of Role 2 create nodes of those three Content types with those webforms. he/she can see submissions of each forms just from each nodes. [ it's solvable. ]
.
now What should I do to create a page by `views` to gather all submissions of all webforms ( or even create a block ) and show them to users of Role 2 without giving access " Administer webform submissions " to them ?!
.
creating such a views is solvable but users of Role 2 have to access " Administer webform submissions " to see all submissions of all webforms in one place, otherwise he/she should see submissions just in it's referenced nodes!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may grant per-form access controls to specific roles.

Just uncheck the "Administer webform submissions" site-wide permission. Then on each webform involved, go to the Settings tab, then the Access section. There, you can provide View access to specific roles by form.

Comment: yes, there is . but it can not solve the problem. the main problem is not about "Viewing the form"!  is about "Viewing Submissions of all Forms in one place". when I go to the Form page I can see that and it's results. but I want to see all submissions of all forms in an arbitrary page (or block) ! @Joseph